# Non-abelian group with infinitely many abelian subgroups

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, examples-counterexamples, abelian-groups

I'm looking for a non-abelian group which has infinitely many abelian subgroups. Do you know any examples of such groups?

Comment: Doesn't a direct product construction get you an example easily?

Comment: Perhaps the "minimal" example in some sense is the [infinite dihedral group](http://groupprops.subwiki.org/wiki/Infinite_dihedral_group).

Answer (score 35, accepted):

Take the product $G = S_3 \times \Bbb Z$, which is non abelian since it has a non-abelian subgroup, namely $S_3$.

However, $\{1\} \times n\Bbb Z$ are abelian subgroups of $G$ for every $n \geq 0$.

Comment: could you please explain to me what's the operation on such group?

Comment: @Angie : the [direct product](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Direct_product_of_groups) of $G$ and $H$ has the following operation : $(g,h) \cdot (g',h') = (gg', hh')$.

Comment: So in our case, for instance $(\text{id}, 3)$ * $(\sigma, 4) = (\sigma, 7)$ where $\sigma \in S_3$ is any permutation.

Answer (score 48):

Any infinite group $G$ must have infinitely many abelian subgroups. Note that for each $x \in G$, there is a cyclic subgroup $\langle x \rangle$, which is abelian. If there is an $x$ such that $\langle x \rangle$ is infinite, then $\langle x \rangle$ has infinitely many abelian subgroups. If no such $x$ exists, there must be infinitely many distinct finite cyclic subgroups $\langle x \rangle$, since otherwise $G$ would be the finite union of finite sets.

Comment: Remarkably, it is impossible not to find an example for the OP question. - Rewording your argument: Each element of $G$ generates an abelian subgroup, and for each such subgroup there are only finitely many generators, hence for infinite $G$, there must be at least $|G|$ many abelian subgroups :)

Comment: Your proof is incomplete. You must proof that there exists at least one infinite group.

Comment: @PyRulez I'd argue otherwise since the existence of such groups is fairly well-known.

Comment: It doesn't prove that a cyclic (sub)group is abelian either. Or that there exists a non-abelian group, let alone an *infinite* non-abelian group. What do you expect in four lines of text, of course it's incomplete, but that doesn't mean it must be made complete ;-)

Comment: This question therefore immediately devolves to "list a bunch of infinite nonabelian groups." Great.

Comment: Jesus. Why don't we ask the answerer to prove $1+1 = 2$ while they're at it? Some things we can take as given.

Comment: Any $x\in G$ induces a subgroup, sure. But how do we pick infinitely many pairwise different (commutative) subgroups? Is this obvious? For instance,  for $G=Z$ we can consider $pZ$ for each prime, I get that.

Answer (score 13):

Consider the subgroups of $\mathrm{SO}(3)$ (visualized as the rotational symmetries of the $2$-sphere) representing rotations about a fixed axis through the center of this sphere.  There are infinitely many choices of this axis, each of which specifies an (abelian) subgroup isomorphic to $\mathrm{U}(1)$.

Answer (score 2):

The set of $2\times 2$ matrices with real entries is non-Abelian when the operator is multiplication, but it has an infinite number of Abelian subgroups.

For example consider any subgroup of the form 
$$\{A | A = \begin{bmatrix} p^n & 0\\ 0 & 1\end{bmatrix} \mbox{ where } n\in \mathbb{Z}\}$$ 
where $p$ is a constant and can be any prime.